# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a small project using VueJS / Axios.
I'm getting an error in my console log :

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined"
```

Since I'm getting and showing the first_name correctly ( i see the result in my page ) the problem just in the console

this is my code :

```
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            collection:{
                data: []
            }
        }
    },
    created: function(){
        getAPI.get('/api/contacts/1/', [{'x':'10'}]).then((response) => {
            this.collection.data = response.data
        })
    }
}
```

HTML code :

```
<span class="d-block info-content">
    {{collection.data.contactInfos.first_name}}
</span>
```

By the way i see the result i see the name, in my HTML, but just i'm wondering about my console log error since the code work perfectly

Comment: The error implies that there's no `contactInfos` property in `collection.data`. Check the spelling and capitalization of the property.

Comment: by the way i see the result in my html ( which it means the spelling is correct )

Comment: That may be coming from somwhere else. Or maybe the error is from some other code.

Comment: This happens since data load is asynchronous, just use optional chaining in your template  {{collection.data?.contactInfos?.first_name}}

Answer (score 3):

You may try to load the data, when it's not there yet, use conditional rendering:

```
<span class="d-block info-content" v-if="collection.data && collection.data.contactInfos">
    {{collection.data.contactInfos.first_name}}
</span>
```

[More information](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

### Update

If `collection.data` is an array then try to show the first element's `contactInfos`:

```
{{collection.data[0].contactInfos.first_name}}
```

Comment: yes you alright / but the condition doesnt change any thing

Comment: Could you add your `response.data` to the question?

Answer (score 3):

For an explanation of what's going on, the `created()` hook does not block. Therefore the rendering of your page merrily proceeds, until your `<span>` element is rendered. At that point, the injection `{{collection.data.contactInfos.first_name}}` is evaluated, and your console logs the given error, which, as the message itself suggests, happens during render.

Later, after the `Promise` in the `created()` hook resolves and `data` is updated, the Vue engine re-renders the components with a dependency on `data`, and the text node inside `<span>` is updated.

To avoid this kind of issue, you must make sure to not reference properties until the loading has completed. You can do this by setting an if condition on your element, for example:

```
<span class="d-block info-content" v-if="!loadingData">
    {{collection.data.contactInfos.first_name}}
</span>
```

and updating `loadingData` only after the promise is resolved:

```js
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            collection:{
                data: []
            },
            loadingData: true
        }
    },
    created: function(){
        getAPI.get('/api/contacts/1/', [{'x':'10'}]).then((response) => {
            this.collection.data = response.data
            this.loadingData = false
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: should i use Created or Mounted, normally ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your response is coming back as unparsed JSON. Can you try:

```
this.collection.data = JSON.parse(response.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the ternary condition, to get rid of this error first, like this

```
{{collection.data.contactInfos ? collection.data.contactInfos.first_name : ""}}
```

then try to figure out where this `property` got missing from that object.